# Graph drawing -Latex (Texlipse)

Tags: graphics

I have to draw Graph and it is my first time, I don't really know how to begin... what do you advice me ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There are lots and lots of types of graphs -- please be a bit more specific as to what you have in mind.

Comment: Have a look at TikZ.

Comment: maybe you want to use Geogebra and export the code to your document

Comment: @Mico i have to draw graphs and i never did it before !! what is the easy way to do so? which ressources ? ......  copy Geogebra I'll take a look at and it seems that this Tikz is bit difficult hhhh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/) you can export a graph to a tikz code.

[image]

You just need to graph the function you want and export it, giving the domain and range of your preference

[image]

**OUTPUT**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0.,0.,1.}
\definecolor{ffqqqq}{rgb}{1.,0.,0.}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw[->,color=black] (-8.,0.) -- (8.,0.);
\foreach \x in {-8.,-6.,-4.,-2.,2.,4.,6.} \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
\draw[->,color=black] (0.,-8.) -- (0.,8.);
\foreach \y in {-8.,-6.,-4.,-2.,2.,4.,6.}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
\draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
\clip(-8.,-8.) rectangle (8.,8.);
\draw [samples=50,rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},xshift=0.cm,yshift=0.cm,color=ffqqqq,domain=-4.0:4.0)] plot (\x,{(\x)^2/2/0.5});
\draw [samples=50,rotate around={-180.:(2.,3.)},xshift=2.cm,yshift=3.cm,color=qqqqff,domain=-5.0:5.0)] plot (\x,{(\x)^2/2/0.5});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is graph data structure can also be draw with ?

Comment: I don't really know but I know that GeoGebra has spreadsheet but I have never used them

Comment: Anyone to help me dudes